# Generate block diagram using tikzpicture with rectangle inside rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am new to tikzpicture bu I am able to generate diagram using the following MWE but I struck at generating the figure as shown in the figure below. Kindly help me to generate a single block.[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\tikzstyle{int}=[draw, fill=darkgray!20, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=12cm]
\tikzstyle{init} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=7.5cm,auto,>=latex']

\node [int] (a) {Version};
\node (b) [left of=a,node distance=5cm, coordinate] {a};
\node [int] (c) [right of=a] {Version};
\node [coordinate] (end) [right of=c, node distance=5cm]{};


\path[->] (a) edge node {Previous Header} (b);
\path[->] (c) edge node {Previous Header} (a);
\draw[->] (end) edge node {Previous Header} (c) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to use absolute coordinates to place the nodes, like \node [int] (a) at (0,0) {abc}; With this you'll find structured way to place all nodes at the wished position.

Comment: You could use relative positioning of nodes with the `positioning` library and use `fit` nodes to plot the surrounding rectangles

Answer (score 1):

Just because it is a useful example for tikz that allows you to draw things that are repeated with some ordinal changes, also because it is not something as simple as it seems, so for that I have used some useful structures if you want to create something like objects, using definitions and moving them using scope. For the positioning of nodes I prefer to use the positioning library you can see it in the chapter 7.11 in [VisualTikz](http://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf).

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc,fit,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Environment Cfg.
        font=\sffamily\bfseries,
        >={Triangle[angle=50:3pt 2]},%from arrows.meta
        %Environment Styles.
        iBox/.style={
            rectangle,
            xscale= 0.75,
            inner sep=0pt,
            minimum height=7mm,
            minimum width=#1,
            rounded corners=3pt,
            draw=black!50,  
            fill=black!5        
        },
        eBox/.style={
            rectangle,
            rounded corners=1pt,
            draw=black!60,
            fill=black!30       
        },
    ]
    %Create repetitive objet with some variables like order name N, N+1 ...
    %\Block[hash block order][block order]{block-coordinate}
    \def\Block[#1][#2]#3{
        \begin{scope}[shift={(#3)}]
            \draw
            (0,0)
                node[iBox=3.5cm](HASH-#2){Hash of block #1} %node[options](can be omitted){text_content}
                node[iBox,inner xsep=7pt, above right = 1.5pt and 0pt of HASH-#2.north west](VER){\scriptsize Version}
                node[iBox,inner xsep=10pt, above left = 1.5pt and 0pt of HASH-#2.north east]{\scriptsize Merkle Root}
                node[iBox,inner xsep=6pt, below right = 1.5pt and 0pt of HASH-#2.south west]{\scriptsize nonce}
                node[iBox,inner xsep=7pt, below left = 1.5pt and 0pt of HASH-#2.south east]{\scriptsize Difficulty Target}
                node[xscale=0.75, below = 1cm of HASH-#2](STE){\small State}
                node[iBox,inner xsep=4pt,below right = 1.5pt and 1.5pt of HASH-#2.south west|-STE.south](BA){\scriptsize Balance}
                node[iBox,inner xsep=4pt,below left = 1.5pt and 1.5pt of HASH-#2.south east|-STE.south](ST){\scriptsize Storage}
            ($(BA)!.5!(ST)$) % use tikzlibrary calc to obtain the middle point between BA and ST
                node[iBox,inner xsep=4pt]{\scriptsize Code}
                node[iBox=3.5cm,below = 1cm of STE](LoT){\scriptsize List of Transactions};
                \begin{scope}[on background layer] % from tikzlibrary backgrounds
                    \node[eBox,fit=(VER)(LoT),outer sep =5pt, label={[xscale=0.75]90:\scriptsize BLOCK #2}](BK-#2){};
                    \node[iBox=3.5cm,inner sep =2pt,fit=(BA)(ST)(STE)]{};
                \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
    }

    %Start drawing the thing.
    \Block[N-1][N]{0,0};
    \Block[N][N+1]{3.5,0};
    \Block[N+1][N+2]{7,0};
    %Draw final details.
    \node[left=-5pt of BK-N,scale=2]{...};
    \node[right=-5pt of BK-N+2,scale=2]{...};
    \draw[->,very thick](HASH-N+1)--(HASH-N);
    \draw[->,very thick](HASH-N+2)--(HASH-N+1);
    \draw[<-,very thick](HASH-N+2.east)--++(1cm,0);

    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @J Leon V.